# Security Policies scope (should they rule seamlessly over data and models)?

Tags: design, security-policy

I'm working on a security policy system design and I'm facing an existential question.

Some of the policies have a model-level scope that could be defined like so :

```
UserGroup x EntityType x AccessMode -> Boolean
```

Meantime, I want to have finer policies that opperate at data-level, to restrain users to access only specific instances.

```
UserGroup x Set<EntityType> x AccessMode -> Boolean
```

In one case, the policy is defined over a Data Model, in one other over Data.
I'm not especially familiar with security policies, is it a bad design to make cohabit two different kind of policies ? Or is it just a misunderstanding that I have, and they work seamlessly ?

**Let's me illustrate this :**

For AccessMode we can use a CRUD-based approach.

Read, Update and Delete mode may operate both over entities and specific instances of entities.
We can write a rule that allows all users belonging to a group Group1 to access any Post in Read mode :

```
Group1 = {User1, User2, ...}
Group1 x Post x Read -> True
```

But, we can also restrain this policy to allow access to specific instances of Post like this :

```
Group2 = {User6, User7, ...}
Group2 x {Post1, Post3, Post4} x Read -> True
```

Here, Users of Group2 can read specific posts Post1, Post3 and Post4, but don't have global permissions over the Post entity.

We can also imagine more complex logic like so :

```
{user in Group1} x {post in Post if post.author = user} x Write -> True
```

Here, users that are allowed to write posts are users that belong to Group1 and that are specifically the author of the post.

Being able to have access control at data-level is important.
But there's at least one case which requires to deal with entity-level policy, which is the Create mode since it defines whether the users may instanciate an entity type and has nothing to do with existing data.

In this case (but could also apply to other access modes) :

```
Group1 = {User1, User2, ...}
Group1 x Post x Create -> True
```

`Post` refers to the entity type.

Comment: Can you give some examples of Model-level policies and Data-level policies?

Comment: Sure, I've added examples.

Comment: Why don't you just accept using both type of policies, type-driven as well as data driven? Wouldn't that solve your whole problem? Honestly, this looks much more like a superstitous gut feeling than a real issue.

Comment: I have no problem with using both type of policies. I was precisely asking whether it is an acceptable solution or if there are better design that could meet my requirements I couldn't see. I just wen to make it the simplest for the users that will define policies seamlessly so they don't have to think whether the policy scope is items or entities. I really like your comment with the comparison with static methods in OOP. I don't think it's a trivial thing for many ppl, that's why I'm trying to make the things easier for the end user, even if there will be different underlaying mechanisms.

Comment: @ibi0tux: you wrote *"make it the simplest for the users that will define policies"* - so you actually will have "users" editing the policies? Are those trained developers or business analysts who have to work with some formal notation or DSL? Or do you have a policy editor in mind? Or is this just for creating a spec, and someone will have to implement the policies manually according to the spec? I am a little bit puzzled at what you are aiming?

Comment: I'm working on the design and development of data-oriented framework using a custom DSL. Users who will create policies can rather be seen as database adminstrators than real developers.

Comment: (Hint: adressing me with the @ mechanics would bring your reponses to my inbox). I guess how easy or hard this will become for your users/administrator depends on the actual DSL, how it will look like, how clear the the precendence rules are, how clear the error messages from a DSL validator are. And I am pretty sure you have understood correctly why having both kind of policies makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not especially familiar with security policies, is it a bad design to make cohabit two different kind of policies ? Or is it just a misunderstanding that I have, and they work seamlessly ?

IMO, it's not a bad design and I think it's only a matter of defining: (1) precedence rules for your co-existing policy levels (and even at the same level -- what happens if there are ambiguous rules? you need to define); (2) default values for when there are no policy defined (e.g.: if nothing is specified, everything is prohibited).

I guess they will not work "seamlessly" until you define a very clear rule of precedence, to avoid creation of ambiguous policies (which might lead to unexpected behaviors at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Just to homogenise your rules a little.

The first rule can be rewritten as: `UserGroup x ∀item in set<EntityType> x AccessMode -> Boolean` where `set<EntityType>` contains all instances of `EntityType`.

The second as `UserGroup x ∀item in set<EntityType> x AccessMode -> Boolean`  where `set<EntityType>` contains some subset of instances of `EntityType`.

The only distinction is how you construct that set.

First Order predicate logic is your friend here. It provides standard logical connectives for combining predicates together, and Each predicate selects for one of:

- All instances of a type
- All instances whose property `x` is in a given range
- The instance is `y`

Which provides allows you to optimise these rules by substituting a simpler predicate/connective graph for a more complex one. Like if the `y` instance has an `x` that is always in range of the other predicate. It can be dropped as an independent check.

It also gives you a framework for automatically finding inconsistencies in the rules. As your entire rulebook can be converted into a decision tree. Any leaf node in that tree that is both true and false is inconsistent.

---

As to how you assign priority to which rule to listen too:

- You can either tell them to give you the rules in precedence order.
- Or you can come up with some way to analyse the specificity of the set to determine which rule is more exact.

If you go down the route of specificity, you will need to decide what to do when two rules have equal specificity but contradict. Most systems will either take the pessimistic approach preferring to agree with `-> false`, or they will never accept a conflicting rule and have already rejected it when the admin went to add it.

Comment: Your point of view seems good but I still don't see how to solve one problem : how to write rules that allow creation of new instances of an EntityType ? The access mode `create` doesn't semantically refer to instances of EntityType but to the EntityType itself. While reading/updating/deleting oppers on data, creating depends on the type, not the existing data. This is what confuses me.

Comment: When checking a Read/Write/Delete security rule you aren't testing the actual file, you are testing a `Request` to `Read/Write/Delete`. `Create` is no different, it tests the `Request` to see if it is acceptable. It might be a trivial test but it is still a test on an instance.

Comment: I think this answer is missing the point. The OP made a case where access policy for Read/Write/Delete depends  on the record (or  "file"), and the acess policy for Create is indeed different, since it does not depend on any existing record, but on the entity type.  This answer looks to me  the classic misunderstanding that "static" methods of a class (in C++, C#, Java, for example) work on "all objects" of that class - which is plain wrong.